# Can anyone tell me how to just pass 2 arguments in the getter and setter method, is it possible to do that or not

Tags: ruby

```
class Student

  # attr_accessor :name

  def name(first_name,last_name)
    @fname=first_name
    @lname=last_name
  end

  def name
    return [@fname,@name]
  end
end

o1=Student.new
o1.name=("tushar")  #i tried this name=("tushar","kumar") but it has error
puts o1.name
```

Comment: The `return` keyword is redundant in your `name` method; you can just specify the array and since it is the last expression evaluated, it will be the return value of the method.

Answer (score 2):

It's rarely used, but a pair of extra parentheses can do the trick:

```
class Student
  def name=((first_name, last_name))
    @fname = first_name
    @lname = last_name
  end

  def name
    return [@fname, @lname]
  end
end

o1 = Student.new
o1.name = "tushar", "kumar"
o1.name #=> ["tushar", "kumar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't really define a method whose names ends with `=` to have more than one argument.  If you really wanted to pass both names, you could define your method as taking an array of 2 names:

```
def name=(array_of_first_then_last)
  @fname, @lname = array_of_first_then_last
end
```

... then call it like this:

```
o.name = ['Kumar', 'Tushar']
```

That said, it's an awkward syntax and is rarely done.

Sometimes, hashes (or keyword arguments) are used for this kind of thing:

```
def name(name_parts)
  @fname = name_parts[:fname]
  @lname = name_parts[:lname]
end

o.name(fname: 'Keith', lname: 'Bennett')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're redefining your `name` method to take no arguments instead of two.  You would want to rename your second method instead.

Also, utilize `@lname` in the return statement so that it doesn't attempt to call a field which doesn't exist.

```
class Student

  # attr_accessor :name

  def name(first_name,last_name)
    @fname=first_name
    @lname=last_name
  end

  def full_name
    return [@fname,@lname]
  end
end
```